# Software to edit HTML Responses?

Tags: web-development, web-browser, web

In the browser's console, you can see all the network connections to the page and their responses.

What software will be able to quickly edit them live in order to test external pages? Will be be Fiddler or something else maybe?

For example, I want to change the word "prod" to "demo":

[image: Responses]

Answer (score 1):

Try BurpSuite.
https://portswigger.net/burp
You can edit requests/responses by using the "intercept" function.